# Best UI interface/Language to query MarkLogic Data

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We will be moving from Oracle and use MarkLogic 8 as our datastore and will be using MarkLogic's Java api to talk with data.
I am exploring for any UI tool (like SQL Developer is there for Oracle), which can be used for ML. I found that ML's Query Manager can used for accessing data. But I see multiple options wrt language:

- SQL
- SPARQL
- XQuery
- JavaScript

We need to perform CRUD operations and search for data, and our testing team is aware of SQL (for Oracle), so I am confused which route I should follow and on what basis I should decide which one/two will be better to explore. We are most likely to use JSON document type.
Any help/suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already mention you will be using the [MarkLogic Java Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java), that should provide most of the common needs you could have, including search, CRUD, facets, lexicon values, and also custom extension though REST extensions as the Client API will be leveraging the MarkLogic REST API. It saves you from having to code inside MarkLogic to a large extent.

Apart from that you can run ad hoc commands from the Query Console, using one of the above mentioned languages. SQL will require the presence of a so-called SQL view (see also your earlier question [Using SQL in Query Manager in MarkLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741156/using-sql-in-query-manager-in-mark-logic)). SPARQL will require enabling the triple index, and ingestion of RDF data.

That leaves XQuery and JavaScript, that have pretty much identical expression power, and performance. If you are unfamiliar with XQuery and XML languages in general, JavaScript might be more appealing.

HTH!

Comment: If you are going to be working with and storing XML documents, then I really think XQuery is the only serious option.

Comment: If XML, there is a difference between the programming logic required in your application and the programming logic needed for document manipulation.

In ML8, they can also take a hybrid approach an consider (1) xQuery for XML document manipulation and (2) Javascript for the rest of their scripting/programming/business logic. (mix and match). 

Having said that, a developer also has access to all of the libraries (like xdmp) from within the Javascript capabilities of ML8, so they could, in theory, do all Javascript.  

If xQuery resource are limited, a hybrid approach could be a viable option.

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your view. We will probably explore between XQuery and JavaScript..